# Query about NaiveBayes Classifier

Tags: classification, probability, naivebayes

I am building a text classifier for classifying reviews as positive or negative. I have a query on NaiveBayes classifier formula:

```
|                       P(label) * P(f1|label) * ... * P(fn|label)
|  P(label|features) = --------------------------------------------
|                                         P(features)
```

As per my understanding, probabilities are multiplied if the events occur together. E.g. what is the probability of A and B occurring together. Is it appropriate to multiply the probabilities in this case? Appreciate if someone can explain this formula in a bit detail. I am trying to do some manual classification (just to check some algorithm generated classifications which seem a tad off, this will enable me to identify the exact reason for misclassification).

In basic probability terms, to calculate p(label|feature1,feature2), we have to multiply the probabilites to calculate the occurrence of feature 1 and feature 2 together. But in this case I am not trying to calculate a standard probability, rather the strength of positivity/negativity of the text. So if I sum up the probabilities, I get a number which can identify the positivity/negativity quotient. This is a bit unconventional but do you think this can give some good results. The reason is the sum and product can be quite different. E.g. 2*2 =4 but 3*1 = 3

Answer (score 0):

The class-conditional probabilities P(feature|label) can be multiplied together if they are statistically *independent*. However, it's been found in practice that Naive Bayes still produces good results even for class-conditional probabilities that are not independent. Thus, you can compute the individual class-conditional probabilities P(feature|label) from simple counting and then multiply them together.

One thing to note is that in some applications, these probabilities can be extremely small, resulting in potential numerical underflow. Thus, you may want to *add* together the *logs* of the probabilities (rather than multiply the probabilities).

Comment: In basic probability terms, to calculate p(label|feature1,feature2), we have to multiply the probabilites to calculate the occurrence of feature 1 and feature 2 together. But in this case I am not trying to calculate a standard probability, rather the strength of positivity/negativity of the text.  So if I sum up the probabilities, I get a  number which can identify the positivity/negativity quotient. This is a bit unconventional but do you think this can give some good results. The reason is the sum and product can be quite different. E.g. 2*2 =4 but 3*1 = 3

Comment: @AmitAgarwal: I don't think that's the correct approach. Please up vote my answer if you find it useful.

Comment: @ stackoverflowuser2010, please see my answer above. Couldn't fit it in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I understand if the features were different like what is the probability of a person being male if the height was 170 cm and weight 200 pounds. Then these probabilities have to be multiplied together as these conditions (events) occur together. But in case of text classification, this is not valid as it really  doesn't matter if the events occur together.. E.g. the probability of a review being positive given the occurrence of word best is 0.1 and the probability of a review being positive given the occurrence of word polite is 0.05, then the probability of the review being positive given the occurrence of both words (best and polite)  is not 0.1*0.05. A more indicative number would be the sum of the probabilities (needs to be normalized),